# Indicate that text is a proper noun (such as a product name)

Tags: fonts, typography, text

How do I indicate that certain words are a product name (in cases where it's not obvious)?

- "Delightful apple cake" is excellent.
- *Delightful apple cake* is excellent.
- **Delightful apple cake** is excellent.
- Or, perhaps, a different font, font size, ...

Or maybe just leave it like the rest of the text?

**EDIT**

Though a general solution to be applied wherever the need arises would be preferable, I am mainly interested in the case of paragraph text on a webpage describing the product. The product name might appear more than once on it.

Comment: There's thousands if not millions of ways to do this depending on the larger composition. There's also ways to say this more effectively without confusion. If you provide some more information this could be an interesting question but as it stands I think its too broad. I would at least start by capitalizing the entire name if the full name is, "Delightful Apple Cake"

Comment: Thanks. But I'm looking for a general solution to be applied wherever the need arises, not for a case-by-case solution. Perhaps, though, there _is_ no general solution. That would be an acceptable answer. I agree about the capitalization.

Comment: Fair enough, but we don't even know if you're designing an ad, a website, a text document, etc. Even a general solution needs more information IMO than what you provided

Comment: @Ryan I edited the question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general answer for this but typically bold, capitalization or even all caps, and a color change would be a good starting point.

> We've worked hard to ensure Delightful Apple Cake is the best pre-packaged apple cake available.

Capitalization alone makes it more apparent

> We've worked hard to ensure **Delightful Apple Cake** is the best pre-packaged apple cake available.

Color change I can't do on here natively without posting a screenshot but it can be with bold or without.

Another thing to note is if the product or brand is registered and/or trademarked that can be used as a good indicator as well

> We've worked hard to ensure Delightful® Apple Cake is the best pre-packaged apple cake available.

A final subtle clue was the inclusion of a lower-case "apple cake" further differentiating one is a name the other is a thing.